# how to make autocomplete or autosuggest in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, autocomplete

I have make a demo of auto suggest  . I have **name(string) and code(string)** .I have around 2000 name with their codes ..So I take string array and put it in this format **name-(code)**   example **"Alexandra Palace-(AAP)"**,.my problem is that I need to filter using code not by name .Actually when I type in input field it match with name not with code .But I need to filter with code.

example
when I type "lwy" it will not show **"MNCRLWY-(LWY)"**, can you please tell how I will achieve this ?

I try like this

```
public class GlobalList {

    public static String[] stationList={

        "MNCRLWY-(LWY)",
        "Lympstone Commando-(LYC)",
        "Lydney-(LYD)",
        "Lye-(LYE)",
        "Lympstone Village-(LYM)",
        "Lymington Pier-(LYP)",
        "Lymington Town-(LYT)",
        "Lazonby & Kirkoswald-(LZB)",
        "Leeds, Whitehall (Bus)-(LZZ)",
        "Macclesfield-(MAC)",
        "Maghull-(MAG)",
        "Maidenhead-(MAI)",
        "Malden Manor-(MAL)",
        "Manchester Piccadilly-(MAN)",
        "Martins Heron-(MAO)",
        "Margate-(MAR)",
        "Manors-(MAS)",
        "Matlock-(MAT)",
        "Mauldeth Road-(MAU)",
        "Mallow-(MAW)",
        "Maxwell Park-(MAX)",
        "Maybole-(MAY)",
        "Millbrook (Hampshire)-(MBK)",
        "Middlesbrough-(MBR)",
        "Moulsecoomb-(MCB)",
        "Metro Centre-(MCE)",
        "March-(MCH)",
        "Marne La Vallee-(MCK)",
        "Morecambe-(MCM)",
        "Machynlleth-(MCN)",
        "Manchester Oxford Road-(MCO)",
        "Manchester Victoria-(MCV)",
        "Maidstone Barracks-(MDB)",
        "Maidstone East-(MDE)",
        "Midgham-(MDG)",
        "Middlewood-(MDL)",
        "Maiden Newton-(MDN)",
        "Morden South-(MDS)",
        "Maidstone West-(MDW)",
        "MAERDY-(MDY)",
        "Meols Cop-(MEC)",
        "Meldreth-(MEL)",
        "Menheniot-(MEN)",
        "Meols-(MEO)",
        "Meopham-(MEP)",
        "Merthyr Tydfil-(MER)",
        "Melton-(MES)",
        "Merthyr Vale-(MEV)",
        "Maesteg (Ewenny Road)-(MEW)",
        "Mexborough-(MEX)",
        "Merryton-(MEY)",
        "Morfa Mawddach-(MFA)",
        "Minffordd-(MFD)",
        "Minffordd-(MFF)",
        "Milford Haven-(MFH)",



};

}
```

**CustomAdapter** :

```
public class CustomAutocompletAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{

    private  String stationNameAndCodeValue ;
    ArrayList<String> autolistArray;
    ArrayList<String> objects;
    private Context context;
    public CustomAutocompletAdapter( Context context, String[] autolistArray){
        this.autolistArray=new ArrayList<String>();
     for(int i=0;i<autolistArray.length;i++){
   this.autolistArray.add(autolistArray[i]);

    }        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return autolistArray.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return autolistArray.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return  position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_adapter, null);
            }

            final TextView stationNameAndCode = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.item_selectStationName);



            stationNameAndCodeValue = autolistArray.get(position);


            stationNameAndCode.setText(stationNameAndCodeValue);


            return v;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Filter myFilter = new Filter() {

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                    FilterResults results) {

                System.out.println("Constraint " + constraint);
                Log.d("-----------", "publishResults");
                  if (results.count > 0 && results != null) {
                objects = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;

                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }


            }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                   Log.d("-----------", "performFiltering");
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults(); 
            List<String> FilteredArrList = new ArrayList<String>();

            if (objects == null) {
               objects = new ArrayList<String>(autolistArray); // saves

            }


                Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();

                constraint = (String) constraint
                        .toString().toLowerCase(locale);
                if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {

                    // set the Original result to return
                results.count = objects.size();
                results.values = objects;

                } else {
               for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
                    String name= objects.get(i);


                    String newName = name.substring(name.indexOf('('),name.length()-1);
                    if (newName.toLowerCase(locale).contains(constraint)) 
                    {
                          FilteredArrList.add(name);
                    }
                }
                // set the Filtered result to return
                results.count = FilteredArrList.size();

                results.values = FilteredArrList;

                }
                return results;
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //convert object to string
                Log.d("-----------", "convertResultToString");
                return "";
            }
        };
        return myFilter;
    }

}
```

Main Activity :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.select_station);

         autocompleteView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.item_autoComplete);

         STATION_LIST = new String[GlobalList.stationList.length
                                            + GlobalExtendStationList.stationList.length];
                                    System.arraycopy(GlobalList.stationList, 0, STATION_LIST, 0,
                                            GlobalList.stationList.length);
                                    System.arraycopy(GlobalExtendStationList.stationList, 0,
                                            STATION_LIST, GlobalList.stationList.length,
                                            GlobalExtendStationList.stationList.length);
                                    autosuggestAdapter = new CustomAutocompletAdapter(this,STATION_LIST);
                                    autocompleteView.setAdapter(autosuggestAdapter);
```

**Xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity=""
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Choose station"
              android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/item_autoComplete"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:ems="10"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
             android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:text="AutoCompleteTextView" >

            <requestFocus />
        </AutoCompleteTextView>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**As you are checking the searching string in the whole string(name), so if it founds the serching string anywhere in the name then it adds to the resut.**
So Use this

```
           String newName = name.subString(indexOf('('),name.lastIndexOf(')'));
           if (newName.toLowerCase(locale).contains(constraint)) 
           {
                 FilteredArrList.add(name);
           }
```

instead of

```
           if (name.toLowerCase(locale).contains(constraint)) 
           {
                 FilteredArrList.add(name);
           }
```

Comment: it is not working ..do you have any id ..it is not filtering not with as name not with code now ..:(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63580/discussion-between-pallavi-sharma-and-nitesh-singh).